# Socket programming - API doubt

Tags: sockets, network-programming, listen

There was this question posted in class today about API design in socket programming.

Why are listen() and accept() provided as different functions and not merged into one function?

Now as far as I know, listen marks a connected socket as ready to accept connections and sets a max bound on the queue of incoming connections. If accept and listen are merged, can such a queue not be maintained?

Or is there some other explanation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `listen()` means "start listening for clients"
- `accept()` means "accept a client, blocking until one connects if necessary"

It makes sense to separate these two, because if they were merged, then the single merged function would block. This would cause problems for non-blocking I/O programs.

For example, lets take a typical server that wants to listen for new client connections, but also monitor existing client connections for new messages.  A server like this typically uses a non-blocking I/O model so that it is not blocked on any one particular socket.  So it needs a way to "start listening" on the server socket without blocking on it.  Once listening on the server socket has been initiated, the server socket is added to the bucket of sockets being monitored via `select()` (called `poll()` on some systems).  The `select()` call would indicate when there is a client pending on the server socket.  Then the program can then call `accept()` without fear of blocking on that socket.

Comment: Oh I guessed as much. I thought one couldnt maintain many connections simultaneously. Thanks.

Comment: @ryan happy to be able to help

Answer (score 1):

[`listen(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/listen.2.html) makes given TCP socket a *server socket*, i.e. creates a queue for accepting connection requests from the clients. Only the listening side port, and possibly IP address, are *bound* (thus you need to call [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html) before `listen(2)`). [`accept(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/accept.2.html) then actually takes such connection request from that queue and turns it into a *connected socket* (four parts required for two-way communication - source IP address, source port number, destination IP address, and destination port number - are assigned). `listen(2)` is called only once, while `accept(2)` is usually called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, `bind` assigns an address and a port to a socket descriptor. It means the port is now reserved for that socket, and therefore the system won't be able to assign the same port to another application (an exception exists, but I won't go into details here). It's also a one-time-per-socket operation.

Then `listen` is responsible for establishing the number of connections that can be queued for a given socket descriptor, and indicate that you're now willing to receive connections.

On the other hand, `accept` is used to dequeue the first connection from the queue of pending connections, and create a new socket to handle further communication through it. It may be called multiple times, and generally is. By default, this operation is blocking if there are no connections in the queue.

Now suppose you want to use an async IO mechanism (like epoll, poll, kqueue, select, etc). If listen and accept were a single API, how would you indicate that a given socket is willing to receive connections? The async mechanism needs to know you wish to handle this type of event as well.

With quite different semantics, it makes sense to have them apart.